# How to implement convolution in Graph convolution recurrent neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network, graph-neural-network

I'm currently trying to understand this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.01926
The author defines convolution on a graph (p.5) and later constructs Graph Convolutional Gated Recurrent Unit.(p.6)
[image: Graph convolution]

The problem is that author uses graph convolution for h_t-1 when it is only defined for signal on a graph of size equal to a number of nodes in the graph when h_t-1 can have arbitrary form depending on the number of units in the GRU cell.

So, is there some problem with my understanding or with the paper?

Comment: https://github.com/youngjoo-epfl/gconvRNN Found correct implementation.